# how to do click and view search bar in ionic 2 application

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript2.0

How to code the click and view search bar in ionic 2 application. In that one the search icon only shows first, when i click the search icon the the search bar will show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**ts**

```
export class Page1{
    public toggled: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
       this.toggled = false;
    }

    public toggle(): void {
       this.toggled = !this.toggled;
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div>
    <ion-icon *ngIf="!toggled" (click)="toggle()" name="search"></ion-icon>
    <ion-searchbar
       *ngIf="toggled"
       [(ngModel)]="someValue"
       (ionInput)="searchThis($event)"
       (ionCancel)="cancelSearch($event)"
       (ionClear) = "cancelSearch($event)"
       [showCancelButton]="true">
    </ion-searchbar>
</div>
```

In your `cancelSearch()` you can call `this.toggle()` to show the icon again.

Comment: Ok thanks it works, but a small bug is there when it is run in the ios the heading is colloid with the searchbar.

Comment: HTML `<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color = "orange">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      MyOrder
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-left *ngIf="!toggled" (click)="toggleSearch()">
      <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      </button>
     </ion-buttons>
      <ion-searchbar *ngIf="toggled" [(ngModel)]="searchTerms" (ionInput)="toggleSearch($event)" (ionCancel)="toggleSearch($event)"
       [showCancelButton]="true">
    </ion-searchbar>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>`

Comment: Please. Create a new question, link the `URL` here, post your `html` + `ts` and some explanation about your use case. Markup is kinda shitty in the comments

Comment: when i do this first it return two object then i searched in the search bar it returns single searched object only @ivaro18

Comment: @SanthoshKumar I do not understand you. What Objects do you mean? I don't have your typescript so I have no idea what you're talking about now. Please edit your question with your code or create a new question with your code.

Comment: @Ivaro18, Any ideas how to include a sliding transition animation on this one?

Answer (score 2):

I think @Ivaro18's answer is perfect.

I would just like to complement with my example set up according to his response.

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component( {
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    toggled: boolean;
    searchTerm: String = '';
    items: string[];

    constructor( public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams ) {
        this.toggled = false;
        this.initializeItems();        
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log( 'ionViewDidLoad HomePage' );
    }

    toggleSearch() {
        this.toggled = this.toggled ? false : true;
    }

    initializeItems() {
        this.items = ['Amsterdam','Bogota','Mumbai','San José','Salvador']; 
     }    

    triggerInput( ev: any ) {
        // Reset items back to all of the items
        this.initializeItems();
        // set val to the value of the searchbar
        let val = ev.target.value;
        // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
        if (val && val.trim() != '') {
          this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
            return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
          })
        }  
    }
}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button *ngIf="!toggled" ion-button icon-only menuToggle><ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon></button>
    <!-- Title -->
    <ion-title *ngIf="!toggled">In&iacute;cio</ion-title>
    <!-- Search Bar -->
    <ion-searchbar *ngIf="toggled" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" [showCancelButton]="true" (ionCancel)="toggleSearch()" (ionInput)="triggerInput($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    <!-- Search Icon -->    
    <ion-buttons end *ngIf="!toggled">
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="toggleSearch()"><ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-buttons>  
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

More info:
For more information, Check out the [API docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#searchbar).

Comment: how to add focus on the searchbar and open the keyboard when user hit search icon?